# nodejs stream finish callback after pipe is not launched

Tags: node.js, stream, pipe

I need to do some housekeeping after pdf file is saved:

```
docx2pdf(doc, function (pdf) {
    console.log("saving file");
    var pdfFile = fs.createWriteStream("./test2.pdf");
    pdf.on('finish',function(){
        console.log("Finished");
        process.exit();
    }).pipe(pdfFile);
    pdf.end();
    console.log("After save");
}, true, true);
```

But code inside second nested function is never launched. pdf is object from pdfkit library. How can I fix it?

UPD: this approach doesn't work also:

```
docx2pdf(doc, function (pdf) {
    console.log("saving file");
    var pdfFile = fs.createWriteStream("./test2.pdf");
    pdfFile.on('finish',function(){
        console.log("Finished");
        process.exit();
    });
    pdf.pipe(pdfFile);
    //pdf.end();
    console.log("After save");
}, true, true);
```

Comment: `docx2pdf` has to push `null` on the end of the stream. Please post the code of  `docx2pdf`.

Comment: what @Mawi12345 said

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to catch the event `finish` on the pipe object, not on the pdf object:

```
console.log("saving file");

pdf
  .pipe( fs.createWriteStream("./test2.pdf") )
  .on( 'finish', function(){
    console.log("Finished");
  });
pdf.end();

console.log("After save");
```

Answer (score 1):

If `pdf` is a proper NodeJS stream, you can simply pipe it into the write stream and be done. If you want to quit your program after the file is saved, you could do this on 'close'.
Notice: there is no "after saving" state (because you end the process). That `console.log("After save")` line in your code is called *before* the file is saved!

```
docx2pdf(doc, function (pdf) {
    console.log("saving file");
    var pdfFile = fs.createWriteStream("./test2.pdf");
    pdf.pipe(pdfFile);
    pdfFile.on('close',function(){
        console.log("Finished");
        process.exit();
    });
}, true, true);
```

Comment: Note that calling process.exit() is a drastic step. Your program will exit automatically once the event queue is empty. Calling exit() yourself might prematurely end the process and prevent those events from being handled.

Comment: If i don't call exit, then my console app doesn't stop in intellij debugger

Answer (score 0):

`pdf` is meant to be *read from* not *written to*. That means you should be treating it as a Readable stream, so listen for `finish` on `pdfFile` instead and remove `pdf.end()`.

Comment: No, this doesn't help.     
    var pdfFile = fs.createWriteStream("./test2.pdf");
    pdfFile.on('finish',function(){
        console.log("Finished");
        process.exit();
    });
    pdf.pipe(pdfFile); doesn't produce 'Finished' message to the console

Comment: Well, then `pdf` is not ending for some reason. Where is `docx2pdf()` defined?

Comment: Its my code. I am ending pdf manually as you see. But this doesn't help.